# Django model relationships in views and templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on multi-user rss reader. I want to limit display of posts only to those which are unread. I've managed to do this in my single "feed" view as below, but I can't figure out how to do the same in multiple feed aka "category" view.

I've been trying something like here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships but it didn't work for me

Should I change my "category" view code or template code? and if so how would you go about it?

thanks!
-S

models

```
class UserCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=False, max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', always_update='True', unique_with='user')

class Feed(models.Model):
    feed_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    default_title = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    link = models.URLField(blank=True)

class UserFeed(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    category = models.ForeignKey(UserCategory)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', always_update='True', unique_with='user')

class Post(models.Model):
    feed = models.ForeignKey(Feed)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(max_length=512)

class ReadPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

views

```
def feed(request, user_feed_slug):
    user_feed = get_object_or_404(UserFeed.objects.filter(slug=user_feed_slug, user=request.user))
    read_post = ReadPost.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('post')
    posts = Post.objects.select_related().filter(feed=user_feed.feed).exclude(id__in=read_post)

def category(request, user_category_slug):
    user_category = get_object_or_404(UserCategory.objects.filter(slug=user_category_slug, user=request.user))
```

templates

```
feed
    {% for post in posts %}
        {{ post.title }}                    
    {% endfor %}

category
{% for feed in user_category.userfeed_set.all %}
    {{ feed.title }}
    {% for post in feed.feed.post_set.all %}
        {{ post.title }}
        {{ post.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), i.e:

```
@register.filter
def unread(posts, read_posts):
    return posts.exclude(id__in=read_posts)
```

(before you must pass `read_post` to category template context).

Comment: I wasn't familiar with custom filters. I'm not sure how to implement it exactly now? Should I put it here: {% for feed in user_category.userfeed_set.all|unread %} or here  {% for post in feed.feed.post_set.all|unread %} ?? also it should I put with some additional arguments like unread:posts ? I'm trying all of those options but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: You must apply this filter to Post queryset and additionally pass users read posts. So in this example it could be something like this: `{% for post in feed.feed.post_set.all|unread:read_posts %}`.

Comment: After further tweaking worked like a charm ! Dzieki :)

Comment: @sikor: Have you checked for the sql queries. Won't the `exclude` method result in different query for each item?

Answer (score 0):

Try this queryset:

```
def category(request, user_category_slug):
    user_category = get_object_or_404(UserCategory, slug=user_category_slug,
                                           user=request.user))

    feeds = UserFeed.objects.filter(category__slug=user_category_slug, user=request.user)\
                .prefetch_related('feed__post_set')
```

then in your template:

```
{% for feed in feeds %}
    {{ feed.title }}
    {% for post in feed.feed.post_set.all %}
        {{ post.title }}
        {{ post.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried but this did not exclude posts that are read (those stored in ReadPost model. Would you have any other idea?